# java - Queue method help needed

Tags: java, class, queue

I am doing a project in Java and I need to create a queue method.

Every time someone is added to a room, they need to be added to the queue.

I nee to create my own queue object in your program and write methods within the object to add to queue and take from queue.

Every time a customer is added to a room it should use the
queue object method to add the customer’s name to the queue.

When the user selects to display the names of the last 3 customers the code should remove them from the queue one by one (first in first out) and display them as they are removed.

The queue should be based on an array and hold 7 items.

When the queue items reach the end of the array they should be added to the start or the array.

If the queue becomes full then an error message should be displayed and the oldest queue item should be **automatically** removed and displayed.

This is the main body:

```
package hotelcoursework2;

import java.util.*;

public class HotelCourseWork2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Room[] myHotel = new Room[10];
        Queue mq = new Queue();

        int guests = 0;    
        String roomName = null;
        int roomNum = 0;
        String letter = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < myHotel.length; i++) {
            myHotel[i] = new Room();

        }

        do {
            System.out.println("Press E to display empty rooms");
            System.out.println("Press A to add customers to room");
            System.out.println("Press V to view all rooms ");                  
            System.out.println("Press D to delete customers from rooms");
            System.out.println("Or enter 1 to add to queue, 2 to take from queue or 3 display queue");
            System.out.println("Press S to save");
            System.out.println("Press L to load");
            System.out.println("Press X to exit");
            System.out.println("Enter a Letter: ");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            letter = scan.next();

            if (letter.equals("A")) {
                add(myHotel, roomNum, roomName, guests);

                mq.addqueue();
            }
            if (letter.equals("V")) {
                view(myHotel);
            }      
            if (letter.equals("E")){
                empty(myHotel);
            }

            if(letter.equals("D")){
                delete(myHotel, roomNum);
                mq.takequeue();
           }

            if (letter.equals("S")){

            }    

            if(letter.equals("3")){
                mq.displayqueue();
            }


        } while (letter.charAt(0) != 'X');
        System.out.println("Exit successfull");

    }


   private static void add(Room myHotel[], int roomNum, String roomName, int guests) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter room number (0-9) or 10 to stop:");
        roomNum = input.nextInt();
        if (roomNum == 10) {
            System.out.println("Exit successful");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Enter name for room " + roomNum + " :");
        roomName = input.next();
        myHotel[roomNum].setName(roomName);
        System.out.println("Enter how many guests: ");
        guests = input.nextInt();
        myHotel[roomNum].setGuestsInRoom(guests);
        System.out.println("Add customers to queue: ");


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Customer " + myHotel[i].getName() + " has been allocated to room " + i
             + " with " + myHotel[i].getGuestsInRoom() + " guests. ");

        }
    }

   private static void view(Room myHotel[]) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("room " + i + " occupied by " + myHotel[i].getName() );
        }
    }

   private static void empty(Room myHotel[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (myHotel[i].getName().equals("no-one")) {
                System.out.println("room " + i + " is empty");
            }
        }
    }

   private static void delete(Room myHotel[], int roomNum){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter room number you want to delete a customer from: ");
        roomNum = input.nextInt();
        myHotel[roomNum].setName("no-one");

   }



}
```

This is the class I have created for the queue but now I am stuck.The queue should be first in first out.

```
package hotelcoursework2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Queue {

    // be careful - this queue can go over the end of the array
    //the array should be used in a circular way
    private static String qitems[] = new String[7];
    private static int front = 0, end = 0;

    static void addqueue() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter someone to the queue :");
        qitems[end] = input.next();
        end++;

    }

    static void takequeue() {
        if (end > front) {
            System.out.println("Person remove :" + qitems[front]);
            front++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Empty queue");
        }
    }

    static void displayqueue() {
        System.out.println("Queue display: ");
        for (int look = front; look < end; look++) {
            System.out.print(" " + qitems[look]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

}

Comment: I suggest you rename your class to MyQueue (or something to that extent) and ` implements Queue` - implementing standard Queue interface will make sure that your implementation is correct. Your methods should **not** be static, get used to specifying access modifier (default one is **not** the best choice)

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to know how to implement a simple queue.

Unless you have to, using an array is more complicated because you have to deal with resizing the array and moving its contents about.

The simplest queue structure is a linked list, like this:

```
public class Queue<T>
{
  private Node head;
  private Node tail;

  public void add(T value)
  {
    if (head == null)
    {
      head = new Node(null, value);
      tail = head;  
    }
    else
    {
      tail = new Node(tail, value);
    }
  }

  public T peek()
  {
    return head == null ? null : head.value;
  }

  public T take()
  {
    if (head == null)
    {
      return null;
    }
    else
    {
      T value = head.value;
      head = head.next;
      return value;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    stringBuilder.append("[");

    Node current = head;
    while (current != null)
    {
      stringBuilder.append(current.value).append(",");
      current = current.next;
    }

    return stringBuilder.replace(stringBuilder.length() - 1, stringBuilder.length(), "]").toString();
  }

  private class Node
  {
    private Node next;
    private T value;

    public Node(Node previous, T value)
    {
      this.value = value;

      if (previous != null)
      {
        previous.next = this;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This class keeps reference to the `head` and `tail` `Node`s adjusting references in the `Node` chain when new values are added and modifying the `head` reference when values are taken.